# Find asymptotes $e^{-x}-e^{-2x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I should find the asymptotes for $e^{-x}-e^{-2x}$. So I will take limits.

My attempt goes like this:

1) when x → $+\infty$ then $e^{-x}$ → $0$ and so does $e^{-2x}$. Thus: $0$. Quite easy.

2) when x → $-\infty$ then $e^{-x}$ → $\infty$ and so does $e^{-2x}$. So we have $\infty - \infty$ but the right $\infty$ is "bigger" since $e^{-2x}$ dominates over $e^{-x}$ for x close to $-\infty$.

Comment: This is close, but you need to make the notion of 'dominant' more formal.  Hint: try pulling out a factor of $e^{-x}$ from $e^{-x}-e^{-2x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, but absolutely not formal enough. The second case can for example be done as follows:
$$e^{-x}-e^{-2x} = e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})$$
Taking the limit $x\rightarrow-\infty$ you find a limit of the form $\infty\cdot(1-\infty)$, thus giving you $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The horizantal asymptote of the graph is the line $y=0$ since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(e^{-x}-e^{-2x})=0$. But there is no horizontal asymptote as $x\to-\infty$ since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow{-\infty}}(e^{-x}-e^{-2x})=\infty$.

Comment: I do not get it